# How to pass multiple Ids as parameters in url in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to send multiple Ids on server side and i'm using the code below

```
var setData = this.view.data;
var setIds = [];
_.each(setData, function(data) {
            setIds.push(data.id);
});
var setList = JSON.stringify({
  'setList' :setIds 
});
var url =  "/framework/servlet.jsp?activity=SetPreview&action=export&"+setList;
```

This will work fine for limited ids , but in my case the data can have 500 ids, which will create the url too long. Can anyone please help me with this situation ?

Comment: If you *actually* exhaust the url length limit try submitting a POST request and put the data into the body.

Comment: Change the server to accept a POST request instead, and send the data in that payload

Comment: Why do you want to send the ids in the url and not the POST body?

Comment: Have you tried `'...action=export&setList=' + encodeURIComponent(setList)`? Then on server `$_GET['setList']`

Comment: I tried using ajax call and put the JSON setList in data , but i'm not able to access it in server side . Can anyone please help?

Comment: Try to access them serverside with `$setList = explode(',', file_get_contents('php://input'))`

Comment: I'm using Java in serverside